# Travel to Italy and Austria

Tags: schengen-visas, italy, criminal-records

I plan to travel to Italy and then fly from there to Austria later this year.  Has anyone had issues getting through Italy when their passport has revealed that they are a registered sex offender?

Comment: What is your nationality, and where were you convicted of sex offenses?

Comment: AFAIK Italy does not have rules in place that automatically deny entry to registered sex offenders, but being considered a threat to eg internal security  (eg terrorism, drug abuse, child abuse, addiction, other serious crimes).can be a reason to deny entry. IMHO you should reach out to a sex crime lawyer or an Italian consulate for advice

Comment: you don't need to fly from Italy to Austria. There are very good train connections between the 2.

Comment: @njzk2 Indeed, but in order to take a train connection between Italy and Austria, unless the OP is already in Schengen it’s first necessary to be allowed to enter one of them